# why aliases found in root users ~/.bashrc file are not used for standard users by default?

Tags: rhel, rm, alias, conventions

Is there any reason why aliases like

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

found in the `~/.bashrc` file of user root are not used by default for any other users?

Comment: Are you asking about the `rm` alias _specifically_? Note that as a non-RedHat user, I have no clue as to what other aliases RedHat keeps in root's `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Because SysAdmins are a breed apart and a law unto themselves?

Comment: Not only, I can also see an alias for 'cp' and 'mv' as well. I would assume that this could avoid many undesired actions from taking place e.g. removing files, overwriting them with mv, etc.

Comment: The problem with setting those alias for everyone is that not all Unix systems use them. If you learn to assume that the `-i` option for those commands is already in effect, and then move to some other distribution (or even to some other unix-like operating system entirely), you might make destructive mistakes. With RedHat's defaults, you learn to be careful when working as a regular user, but have an extra safety net when running commands as root. Whether this approach works or not is mostly a situation- and opinion-based matter.

Answer (score 6):

Non-root users do not use `~root/.bashrc` for the same reason that they also don't use any other user's `~/.bashrc`—these files are *individual* per-interactive-shell startup files.

If you wish standard aliases or other initializations for all `bash` users on a system, those declarations belong in the systemwide per-interactive-shell startup file `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Comment: I'm unable to locate the /et/chasb.bashrc on my RHEL 7 system. I see /etc/bashrc and /etc/profile.